# UIApplication sharedApplication openURL does not work with File:// (load local pdf file)?

Tags: iphone, ipad

This does not work

```
NSString *myPDF = @"file:///Users/sm/Documents/doc.pdf";
```

This works

```
NSString *myPDF = @"http://www.site.org/doc.pdf";   

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: myPDF]];
```

So should I create a web view and load the pdf on the web view?

Comment: This is tagged iPhone and iPad, but the path you provide does not exist on those devices.  Are you sure this isn't for a desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to take a look at [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

here is a tutorial

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/06/14/ipad-sdk-3-2-document-support-1/